# Object name of that started subroutine using add handler

Tags: vb.net, addhandler

My problem is that when the subroutine runs I don't know which button caused it to be triggered how can I find this out. The variable count needs to be replaced with the delete button number that was clicked.
I cannot have a separate subroutine for each button as I don't know how many the user needs to be added to the form on each occasion.

```
    Dim delete1 = Sub()
        .Remove(label1(count, 1))
        .Remove(combo1(count, 1))
        .Remove(label1(count, 2))
        .Remove(combo1(count, 2))
        .Remove(label(count, 3))

                 End Sub

    For counter = 1 To count
        AddHandler MyClass.button1(counter).Click, delete1
    Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it from the `sender` argument:

```
Private Sub delete1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim curButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button) 'Button you clicked

End Sub
```

Note that the code to add the aforementioned function directly (without `delegate`) is:

```
AddHandler MyClass.button1(counter).Click, AddressOf delete1
```